# Data Structure Undirected Graph in Java

Tags: java, graph, hashmap

Assume an undirected graph where edges have `int` values.

*Example Graph*:

```
A---B---C
    |
    D
```

*Example Edge Values*:

```
A,B : 1
B,C : 2
B,D : 2
```

I am writing a program that does the following: Given a node, return all edges in which the node is involved together with the associated value. For example: IN: B → OUT: (C,2), (D,2). Or IN: C → OUT: (B,2).
I am looking for an efficient data structure to do that. The problem is not derived from graph theory, I just used that to explain it. I am not interested in shortest paths etc., just this kind of data store.

The only thing I could quickly come up with:

```
HashMap<String,Tuple>
```

where

```
class Tuple{
    String node;
    int value;
}
```

I would then put each edge in this set twice, for example (pseudocode):

```
hm.add(A, new Tuple(B,1))
hm.add(B, new Tuple(A,1))
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How about a biMap where you can lookup by key as well as value based on vertex id? In your case it would be Map<Tuple, Tuple>?

Comment: It is not good because of `hm.add(B, new Tuple(C,2))` overwrites `B-A` edge.

Comment: @saka1029 You are right. It has to be HashMap<String, List<Tuple>>.

Comment: @SMA BiMap sounds good but as saka1029 correctly noted, I need something list-like...

Answer (score 1):

How about Guava’s `ValueGraph`?

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained